# Point-N-Click virtual mouse partly working on reFX Nexus

Tags: windows-7, mouse-click, dwell-clicker, fl-studio

I use [Point-N-Click virtual mouse](http://www.polital.com/pnc/) (version: PNC 2.10.1, CPNC 2.5.5, BT 1.0.11, run as admin)  as my dwell clicking software on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

So far it has been able to send mouse clicks in all programs have used, except for the 32-bit VST plugin [reFX Nexus](https://refx.com/nexus/) (version 2.2.0) in FL Studio 12.5.1.

More specifically, Point-N-Click virtual mouse man click on tabs but cannot click on anything in the first tab (in white):

[image]

Point-N-Click virtual mouse version:

[image]

Is there anyway to have Point-N-Click virtual mouse work with reFX Nexus? (i.e., send mouse clicks)

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.